# Play music in lock screen

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uilocalnotification, mpmusicplayercontroller

In alarm app I need to play music when received local notification or after specific period in lock screen.

My solution: I set background mode as audio in plist and when received notification some code will execute which responsible to play music using MPMusicPlayerController.

Apple reject this app because I used background mode .

Who has another way to do this ?